# Php Soap request failed because of authentication error

Tags: php, authentication, soap, ws-security

I'm a little bit out of my comfort zone. I'm trying to create a SOAP request with PHP, and I'm using the famous API of KBO, here's the documentation:

https://economie.fgov.be/sites/default/files/Files/Entreprises/CBE/Cookbook-CBE-Public-Search-Webservice.pdf

So essentially everything went well, but I'm still struggling with something about the authentication, which makes me fail my entire small framework:

```
<?php

$endpoint = 'https://kbopub-acc.economie.fgov.be/kbopubws110000/services/wsKBOPub';
$wsdl = 'https://kbopub-acc.economie.fgov.be/kbopubws110000/services/wsKBOPub?wsdl';
$username = 'myusername';
$password = 'mypassword';

$timestamp = gmdate('Y-m-d\TH:i:s\Z');
$nonce = base64_encode(random_bytes(16));
$passwordDigest = base64_encode(sha1($nonce . $timestamp . $password, true));
$header = '
<wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
    <wsse:UsernameToken>
        <wsse:Username>' . $username . '</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">' . $passwordDigest . '</wsse:Password>
        <wsse:Nonce>' . $nonce . '</wsse:Nonce>
        <wsu:Created xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">' . $timestamp . '</wsu:Created>
    </wsse:UsernameToken>
</wsse:Security>';
$options = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => 'Authorization: WSSE profile=' . $header,
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        ),
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false
        )
    ))
);
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ),
));
$options['stream_context'] = $context;
// $options = array(
//     'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1
// );
$client = new SoapClient($wsdl, $options);

// Set up the request parameters
$enterpriseNumber = '0810.002.854';
$request = array('EnterpriseNumber' => $enterpriseNumber);

// Call the SOAP operation with the request parameters
$response = $client->__soapCall('ReadEnterprise', array($request));

// Get the request and response XML
$requestXML = $client->__getLastRequest();
$responseXML = $client->__getLastResponse();

var_dump($response);
```

I also followed some suggestions from my PHP log file, where it was written to use a different version of the soap version: SOAP_1_1 instead of the SOAP_1_2.

What I find really challenging is the fact that I can't debug it in any way; I have no idea on how I can check the error message, or I can't have any hint in my error log file, it simply mentions the security check, but nothing much.

Has anyone had the same issue?

By the way, the error that I have encountered is the following:

> [14-Feb-2023 17:09:24 UTC] PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught SoapFault exception: [ns1:SecurityError] A security error was encountered when verifying the message in
> Stack trace:
> #0 /Users/mymac/Sites/cboxform/api-call/index.php(55): SoapClient->__soapCall('ReadEnterprise', Array)
> #1 {main}
> thrown in /Users/mymac/Sites/cboxform/api-call/index.php on line 55

TLTR:

To summarize, I would need a request that looks like:

```
<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" xmlns:mes="http://economie.fgov.be/kbopub/webservices/v1/messages" xmlns:dat="http://economie.fgov.be/kbopub/webservices/v1/datamodel">
   <soapenv:Header>
 <mes:RequestContext>
<mes:Id>myid</mes:Id>
<mes:Language>fr</mes:Language>
 </mes:RequestContext>
 </soapenv:Header>
 <soapenv:Body>
 <mes:ReadEnterpriseRequest>
 <dat:EnterpriseNumber>0206231995</dat:EnterpriseNumber>
 </mes:ReadEnterpriseRequest>
 </soapenv:Body>
</soapenv:Envelope>
```

with a header with a digest password, with timestamp and nonce that will expire in 300 seconds to this endpoint:

https://kbopub-acc.economie.fgov.be/kbopubws110000/services/wsKBOPub?wsdl

with also a username.

Comment: SOAP is hellish to debug. At a glance of that documentation it looks like your header is missing the `wsu:Timestamp` element. Try to match it as closely as possible to the documented one and see if it changes anything.

Comment: @Gavin I would feel already lucky enough if I would be able to catch the error somehow

Comment: The `wsse:Security` element is part of the SOAP header. It is *not* part of the `Authorization` HTML header.

Comment: I meant "HTTP header" of course. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/953639/connecting-to-ws-security-protected-web-service-with-php) for more information.

Comment: for SOAP header maybe this comment at php can be of some help : [https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php#107889](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.soapheader.php#107889)

Comment: This answer should help https://stackoverflow.com/a/50847927/892493  You need to handle the call in a try/catch block, and you can also extend the SoapClient class if you need to modify the request or do additional debugging.

Comment: Identical issue described with another SOAP server in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67568839/how-to-properly-generate-security-header-for-soap-request-in-c

Comment: Please note that the KBO documentation refers somewhat informally to 300 seconds, but it might be a default value which is hard once started as described on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41023366/exception-of-an-authentication-soap-request-with-ws-security.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like an issue with the security token that you're using to authenticate your SOAP request.
Please check `timezone` format as UTC `(YYYY-MM-DDTHH:MM:SSZ)`, `Nonce` should be a random value that is generated for each request, and `PasswordDigest` value is calculated correctly, `PasswordDigest` (SHA-1 hash) and concatenated values for `Nonce`, Created `timestamp`, `password` in binary format.

Also you can try to print out the values of the `timestamp`, `nonce`, and `passwordDigest` for easy to debugging

Can you try replace at line 20 within below code:

```
$options = array(
    'soap_version' => SOAP_1_1,
    'trace' => true,
    'exceptions' => true,
    'encoding' => 'UTF-8',
    'cache_wsdl' => WSDL_CACHE_NONE,
    'stream_context' => stream_context_create(array(
        'http' => array(
            'header' => 'Authorization: WSSE ' . $header,
            'user_agent' => 'PHPSoapClient'
        ),
        'ssl' => array(
            'verify_peer' => false,
            'verify_peer_name' => false
        )
    ))
);
$context = stream_context_create(array(
    'ssl' => array(
        'verify_peer' => false,
        'verify_peer_name' => false,
    ),
));
```

WSSE header to use the correct profile value within space after it

Comment: Could you offer your idea? I'm still struggling. I will publish what I would need!

Answer (score 1):

The KBO Public Webservice uses `ns1:SecurityError` as a catch-all exception, which makes it hard to determine the actual cause.

As a first step, I have found it working:

- to run SoapUI,
- then choose Import WSDL from https://economie.fgov.be/sites/default/files/Files/Entreprises/KBO/Cookbook-KBO-Public-Search-Webservice.pdf
- right click on project -> Show project view -> Outgoing WS-Security Configurations -> Add "usernamepassword", in it add Username with Passworddigest and Timestamp with 300000
- Go to Read Enterprise
- click on Request Properties at bottom-left.
- Fill in: Username
- Fill in: Password
- WSS-Password Type: PasswordDigest
- WSS TimeToLive: 300000

This typically works when the language code and enterprise number have been set.

But what is the actual payload?

- On the request window click: Add request to mockservice (third button top left menu)
- Start the mock service.
- On request window select 'http://localhost:8080' or whatever port the mockservice is using.
- On the mock service window: Go to "OnRequest Script".
- Specify `log.info mockRequest.requestContent`.
- Run request in request window.
- In Mock service window: go to script log.
- The actual payload is displayed.

[image: SoapUI of KBO]

Note that a password digest can only be used ONCE. On subsequent use it will also return the catch-all ns1:SecurityError. A sample of a working SQL-implementation is (shown on https://forums.invantive.com/t/uitlezen-kbo-public-search-api-geeft-foutmelding-ns1-securityerror/3424/2):

```sql
--
-- Tested according to http://www.herongyang.com/Web-Services/WS-Security-Validate-Password-Digest-String.html
-- using:
--  l_created := '2014-06-21T12:43:21.791Z';
--  l_password := 'iLoveDogs';
--  l_username := 'herong';
--
declare
  l_nonce                blob;
  l_created              varchar2;
  l_expires              varchar2;
  l_wsse_created         varchar2;
  l_password_digest      varchar2;
  l_xml                  varchar2;
  l_out_contents_char    varchar2;
  l_out_http_status_code int32;
  l_created_date         datetime;
  l_expires_date         datetime;
  --
  l_enterprise_number    varchar2 := '0670979187';
  l_username             varchar2 := 'wsot9999';
  l_password             varchar2 := 'secret';
  l_language_code        varchar2 := 'nl';
  l_msg_id               varchar2 := to_char(newid());
begin
  l_created_date := sysdateutc;
  --
  -- Default maximum offset of wss4j is 300 seconds.
  --
  l_expires_date := l_created_date + 300/86400;
  --
  l_created := to_char(l_created_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"');
  l_expires := to_char(l_expires_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"');
  l_wsse_created := to_char(l_created_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD"T"HH24:MI:SS.FF3"Z"');
  --
  l_nonce:=random_blob(24);
  --
  -- Calculate digested password.
  --
  l_password_digest := base64_encode(hex_to_blob(sha1(l_nonce || to_binary(l_wsse_created) || to_binary(l_password))));
  --
  l_xml := '<soapenv:Envelope xmlns:dat="http://economie.fgov.be/kbopub/webservices/v1/datamodel" xmlns:mes="http://economie.fgov.be/kbopub/webservices/v1/messages" xmlns:soapenv="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '  <soapenv:Header>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-A4DC6AF47AFDBFB025168519485171276">';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '        <wsu:Created>' || l_created || '</wsu:Created>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '        <wsu:Expires>' || l_expires || '</wsu:Expires>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      </wsu:Timestamp>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-A4DC6AF47AFDBFB025168519485171275">';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '        <wsse:Username>' || xmlencode(l_username) || '</wsse:Username>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordDigest">' || xmlencode(l_password_digest) || '</wsse:Password>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '        <wsse:Nonce EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">' || xmlencode(l_nonce) || '</wsse:Nonce>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '        <wsu:Created>' || l_wsse_created || '</wsu:Created>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      </wsse:UsernameToken>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '    </wsse:Security>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '    <mes:RequestContext>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      <mes:Id>' || xmlencode(l_msg_id) || '</mes:Id>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      <mes:Language>' || xmlencode(l_language_code) || '</mes:Language>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '    </mes:RequestContext>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '  </soapenv:Header>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '  <soapenv:Body>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '    <mes:ReadEnterpriseRequest>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '      <dat:EnterpriseNumber>' || xmlencode(l_enterprise_number) || '</dat:EnterpriseNumber>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '    </mes:ReadEnterpriseRequest>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '  </soapenv:Body>';
  l_xml := l_xml || chr(13) || chr(10) || '</soapenv:Envelope>';
  --
  select htp.CONTENTS_CHAR
  ,      htp.http_status_code
  into   l_out_contents_char
  ,      l_out_http_status_code
  from   HTTPDownload@DataDictionary
         ( url => 'https://kbopub-acc.economie.fgov.be/kbopubws110000/services/wsKBOPub'
         , acceptMimeType => '*/*'
         , contentType => 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8'
         , method => 'POST'
         , textPayload => l_xml
         , ignoreWebError => false
         ) htp
  ;
  dbms_output.put_line(l_out_contents_char);
end;
```